# viewForHeaderInSection and titleForHeaderInSection are both called

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, iphone

I have the following classes:
`ParentVC:UITableViewController` and `SubClassVC:ParentVC` which both implement `titleForHeaderInSection`.

However, I want to start using a custom header view in `SubClassVC` and so I have added `viewForHeaderInSection` in `SubClassVC`. I noticed that both `viewForHeaderInSection` and `titleForHeaderInSection` in `SubClassVC` get called even though `viewForHeaderInSection` should have precedence. If I remove `titleForHeaderInSection` from `SubClassVC`, the `ParentVC` one is still called leading to the same issue. Both being called is leading to duplicate overlapping headers.

Any ideas how I can stop `titleForHeaderInSection` from being called as well? Is this supposed to be the case?  This is in Obj-C but can also be a problem in Swift.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// other code
    return view;
}

- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: [ganoncookie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17844193/ganoncookie) Can you please share the code? I've tried your case in a new project, and `viewForHeaderInSection` is only called.

Comment: I really do just have both functions in my obj-c class. Do you have a similar inheritance structure? @RamyRizkalla

Comment: I read somewhere that this double-call might be happening if the UIView I am returning is UITableViewHeaderFooterView. Are you returning UITableViewHeaderFooterView or a subclass of it? @RamyRizkalla

Comment: I'm returning simple UIlabel.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use composition instead of inheritance.
Instead of relying on the parent to implement the UITableViewDataSource protocol, you could implement it yourself in SubClassVC, and when implementing - reuse the ParentVC's code. One way to reuse that code is to refactor the data source methods to a separate class (extract those methods to a new class MyTableDataSource, and then create and call it in both ParentVC's and SubClassVC).